# Create a Spring Boot 1.5.8 Quartz scheduler app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I want to create a Spring Boot Quartz  scheduler app. using Spring Boot 1.5.8 with Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.9.0.RELEASE using the option Spring Starter Project, but the Quartz  scheduler option is disabled:

[image]

I also tried to added manually adding to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

and then I got the error:

```
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz:jar is 
 missing.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create your spring-boot starter app with version >= `2.0.0.M2`. At [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) you can see for which version some dependencies are available.

[image]

After using the correct version, everything should work.

Comment: I use spring boot 1.5.9, can I still use Quartz without upgrading?